# add an integer to a specific index of a list

Tags: python, list

How could I add an integer to a specific index of a list?
For instance:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]    # Add 1 to x[1]
```

The result should be:

```
[1,3,3,4]
```

I want to know if there is any method like `.append()` to achieve such a result besides `x[1] += 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

```
x[1] += 1
```

but you could also just use straight-up assignment here:

```
x[1] = x[1] + 1
```

In this case, the two forms are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I kept my answer deliberately simpler than that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: even if `x[1]` is a mutable object, it *depends on how `__radd__` is implemented* what happens. E.g. a complete discussion of the subject would add several paragraphs where for this simple case, my short explanation suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reference element 1 of x:

```
x[1] = x[1] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Just give index number of the array..

```
x[1] = x[1] + 1
```